# Making a sliding image gallery using CSS

Tags: css, gallery, slideshow, css-transitions

I want to make a pure CSS gallery/slideshow, which would use a sort of "push" transition effect (if you've ever used Keynote, you probably know what I mean). The center image would be fully visible, while the images to the side would be masked as they would overflow outside of the column containing the slideshow. Also, is it possible to make the transitions timed?

Comment: you mean like the topbar of https://play.google.com/store?hl=en ?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do it in CSS3 with no JS at all, at the cost of being horribly complicated, not cross-browsers compatible and with lesser maintenability. What controls do you need (Pause/Stop and/or Prev/Next or nothing?). It's FAR more easier and compatible to do it in jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stick to my comment under your question but here's a CSS3 slideshow with controls, made by one of my colleague: **[Full CSS3/HTML5 slideshow](http://creativejuiz.fr/trytotry/juizy-slideshow-full-css3-html5/)**

This is (ridiculously) complicated, doesn't work everywhere, took him weeks and many iterations to achieve, etc
And the text of controls are `&lt;` for example when it should be `Previous image`... Meh

As a challenge, nice work. In production, certainly not today.